# How to increment column with Laravel Eloquent updateOrCreate()?

Tags: laravel

Is it possible to return the model `id` from the request below ?

```
Bar::insert([
  'foo_id' => Foo::updateOrCreate([
    'code' => $row[0],
    'name' => $row[1]
  ])->increment('count')->id
]);
```

I also tried this:

```
Foo::updateOrCreate([
  'code' => $row[0],
  'name' => $row[1]
], [
  'count' => DB::raw('count + 1')
])->id
```

But it doesn't work at inserting because it `count` is not yet set.

> HINT:  There is a column named "count" in table "foos", but it cannot be referenced from this part of the query. (SQL: insert into "public"."foos" ("id", "name", "count") values (123, Hello, count+1) returning "id")

=== EDIT ===

With `DB::raw('IFNULL(count,0) + 1')`, I'm getting:

```
  SQLSTATE[42703]: Undefined column: 7 ERROR:  column "count" does not exist
LINE 1: ... ("code", "name", "count") values ($1, $2, IFNULL(count,0) +...
                                                             ^
HINT:  There is a column named "count" in table "foos", but it cannot be referenced from this part of the query. (SQL: insert into "public"."foos" ("code", "name", "count") values (123, Hello, IFNULL(count,0) + 1) returning "id")
```

Comment: you can create migration `$table->increments('count');`

Comment: @KamleshPaul I'm getting the error message `multiple primary keys for table "foos" are not allowed`

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately I don't think this is possible to reference the `count` column only when the update happens (since this is what is happening here). You will need to take the roundabout way:

```
   $model = Foo::firstOrNew([
      'code' => $row[0],
      'name' => $row[1]
   ]);
   $model->count = ($model->exists ? $model->count : 0) + 1; 
   $model->save();
```

Here `$model->exists` will be `true` if the model was retrieved from the database or `false` if a new one was created.

Efficiency-wise `firstOrCreate` is what `updateOrCreate` does anyway so there's no query cost added

Answer (score 1):

try using [IFNULL](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_ifnull.asp)

```
Foo::updateOrCreate([
  'code' => $row[0],
  'name' => $row[1]
], [
  'count' => DB::raw('IFNULL(count,0) + 1')
])
```

if you want the id, try it like this:

```
$id=(Foo::updateOrCreate([
  'code' => $row[0],
  'name' => $row[1]
], [
  'count' => DB::raw('IFNULL(count,0) + 1')
]))->id;
```

note: this is working on mysql, not PostgreSQL

Comment: I'm getting this error: `HINT: There is a column named "count" in table "foos", but it cannot be referenced from this part of the query. (SQL: insert into "public"."foos" ("id", "name", "count") values (123, Hello, IFNULL(count,0) + 1) returning "id")`

Comment: This won't work because at the point of `INSERT` the `count` column is not null. It does not exist at all so you can't make any assertions that use it

Comment: strange enough, I have tested on laravel 7.3 and it works

Comment: How do you set the `count` column in your migration ? Mine is set with `$table->integer('count')`

Comment: $table->unsignedInteger('count');

Comment: I think the fact that it works is a MySQL quirk (or a quirk of some DBMSs). It won't work in Postgres I think. Generally it's undefined behaviour so probably not something to rely on

Comment: @apokryfos Indeed, I'm using PostgreSQL

Comment: @OMR I have updated my post with full error message

Comment: Take a look at http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/dd2bc4 it works for MySQL but that's about it, if you try to build it on other DBMS it generally does not work (it also seems that `IFNULL` is not SQL standard since in MS SQL it's `ISNULL` )

Comment: @OMR I get the same error with the updated part `$id=(...)->id`

Answer (score 0):

you just need to set column auto-increment in database and not need set it column in your eloquent

Comment: Auto increment column but be primary, and only one primary key is possible, I already have it with `$table->id();` in my migration.

Comment: I think this is not a proper solution

Comment: if count column is unique and increment why not use it as primary why u need to 2 increment column in the same table

Comment: if you need to do count column increment and let id column you can do it with trigger